# unable to comile PostgreSQL with error message "could not find shared library for Python"

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, msys2, postgresql-10

I've been trying to build the *REL_10_STABLE* version of `PostgreSQL` using [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) in windows 10 environment.
Here is the command that I execute for configuring the build:

> ./configure --enable-thread-safety --enable-nls --with-ldap
>   --with-openssl --with-ossp-uuid --with-libxml --with-libxslt --with-icu --with-tcl --with-perl --with-python

but I get this error message:

> checking for python... no
>   checking for python3... no
>   checking for python2... /mingw64/bin/python2
>   checking for Python distutils module... yes
>   checking Python configuration directory... C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python2.7/config
>   checking Python include directories... -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/python2.7
>   checking how to link an embedded Python application... configure: error: could not find shared library for Python
>   You might have to rebuild your Python installation.  Refer to
>   the documentation for details.  Use --without-python to disable building
>   PL/Python.

As you can see python 2.7 is installed which is the version I need to use and I need the python to be built with python, but I keep getting the error message `"could not find shared library for Python"`.
Any help is very much appreciated.

Thank you
Sam

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have built your python executable without the --enable-shared flag.

The PostgreSQL documentation says the following:

> Since PL/Python will be a shared library, the libpython library must be a shared library also on most platforms. This is not the case in a default Python installation built from source, but a shared library is available in many operating system distributions. configure will fail if building PL/Python is selected but it cannot find a shared libpython. That might mean that you either have to install additional packages or rebuild (part of) your Python installation to provide this shared library. When building from source, run Python's configure with the --enable-shared flag.